# Nothing but 'run(); ' when browsing to my local project, how do I fix this?

Tags: php, apache2, yii2

I just added a new project. I made a mistake in the projectname.conf file in sites-available from apache2, which led me to reinstalling apache2.

After reinstalling and re-enabling my projects all I get on every page of every project is

```
..
<body>
   run();
</body>
..
```

I've run a composer update, restarted the service, restarted my pc, checked my config files, tried disabling the new project.

There is nothing in my error log, and this is my access.log:

`127.0.0.1 - - [15/May/2015:01:40:47 +0200] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 304 181 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:38.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/38.0"`

Maybe I'm forgetting something for the apache2 reinstall? I don't think I did anything different as to last time I installed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you haven't setup PHP correctly.
Take a look at [this great guide](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-linux-apache-mysql-php-lamp-stack-on-ubuntu), maybe you're forgetting to link the PHP config to Apache2.

Comment: I thought I would not have to re-apply certain settings, turns out I did. Thanks for the guide.